# Samba Linux server MacOS client ACLs

Tags: linux, mac-osx, samba, access-control-list

I'm trying to enable ACLs for a Linux Server using a MacOS client.

My configuration is as follows:

```
[global]
        vfs objects = acl_xattr
        map acl inherit = yes
        store dos attributes = yes

        logging = systemd
        workgroup = FAIRY
        server string = Fairy Test Server
        server role = standalone server
        hosts allow = 192.168.202. 172.0.0.1
        dns proxy = no
        unix extensions = yes
[share]
        path = /srv/smb/
        browsable = yes
        writeable = yes
        read only = no
```

However when I try to use chmod +a on the Mac it is giving me "Operation not supported".
It this not supported or am I doing something wrong?
I know that when using AD to mount the user share it is working, so I'm assuming there must be some sort of configuration that allows this.